# How to use map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function `mostraReferti` where i get a list of items from the database and store them in the state into `referti[]`. I need to display those items in a dropdown. I first tried to write  `{this.state.referti}` in `<option>` but what i got was only the first item of the table. I need to use `map()`. So i tried this code:

```
class CredentialsPanel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      referti: []
     }
     this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
     this.mostraReferti = this.mostraReferti.bind(this);
   }

   static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
     const { account } = nextProps
     return { id: account.id }
  }

   handleInputChange(event) {
     const target = event.target;
     const value =
       target.type === 'checkbox'
         ? target.checked
         : target.value;
     const name = target.name;
  console.log("stato", this.state)
     this.setState({
       [name]: value,
     });
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     const { actions } = this.props

     requestAccountAccess((defaultAccount) => {
       actions.account.setDefaultAccount(defaultAccount)
       actions.contract.setContract(defaultAccount)
     })
    this.mostraReferti(this.state.id)   
   }

   mostraReferti(id) {
     console.log("id", id)
     axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/REFERTOs/' + id)
       .then(response => {
         console.log("response1" + JSON.stringify(response.data))
        this.setState({ referti: response.data }, () => {
             console.log(this.state);
           })
         return response.data
       })
     }

   onEnter = (evt) => {
     if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
       const { allowToProceed } = this.state
       if (allowToProceed) { this.proceed() }
     }
   }

    proceed = () => {
     const { actions, history } = this.props
     const { codiceReferto } = this.state   
     actions.account.setCodiceReferto(codiceReferto)
     history.push('/consenso?panel=2')
   }

 render() {
     const { id, nextBtnDisabled } = this.state
     const refertiItems = this.state.referti.map((referti, i) => {
       return (
         <RefertiItems key={referti.hash_referto} item={referti} />
       )
     })

     return (
       <div className={styles}>
         <h2>Compila i campi per assegnare un consenso</h2>
         <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           <div className="form-section">

      <br />
          <div className= "custom-select"  >
            {refertiItems}
          </div>
         <br />
  </div>
         </Form>
     )
   }
 }
```

And RefertiItems is:

```
 class RefertiItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            item: props.item
        } 
    }  

render(){
return (
    <div  classname= "custom-select">
   <Label for="type" text="Codice Referto" />
    <select
      name="codiceReferto"
       placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
      onKeyPress={this.onEnter}     //allows you to move to the next panel with the enter key
      value={this.codiceReferto}
      onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
      <option default value="vuoto"></option>
      <option value={this.state.item.hash_referto}> . 
   {this.state.item.tipo_referto}-{this.state.item.data_referto}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
)
}
}
```

what i get is *"this.state.referti.map is not a function"*, and the system displays a different select for every item in the table of the database.

Comment: Those are very long snippets of code for a question titled "How to use map()?"...

Comment: Probably because this.state.referti is no longer an array when you use setState() to update it with the response.data. Can you confirm what your response.data looks like. It's most likely an object.

Comment: i think it's an array of objects :           response1[{"hash_referto":"e9cceea77b26d2090649a923116a35882088d23378b0ad10ff48d139ae3db1da","proprietario":"050708","public_key":"0x7343197ba6ee64b5f07322ce1acb0f8f29897689","data_esame":"2019-08-23T00:00:00.000Z","tipo_esame":"urologia","uri":null},{"hash_referto":"5bad691600ade15abc5949ba8b089e0699071b72e503364fd0e05438a4b4581d","proprietario":"230888","public_key":"0x9628ade5057141a66018b63b78cbdc4a44f055b2","data_esame":"2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z","tipo_esame":"pediatra","uri":null}]

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats just an object, that has a property named response1, and its value is an array of objects

Comment: console.log("response1" + JSON.stringify(response.data)), that's response1

Comment: I see an issue on your `RefertiItems` as it just have a single item, an it should have all. The result you have of multiple select components is for that reason, you should move the map loop in `RefertiItems`.

Comment: just like Radonirina Maminiaina said. I tried but it still says "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.item.map is not a function" and " Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.props.item.map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

You should pass directly your `referti` array as a prop of `RefertiItems` .

`ReferiItems` class:

```
class RefertiItems extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item: props.item
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div classname="custom-select">
        <Label for="type" text="Codice Referto" />
        <select
          name="codiceReferto"
          placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
          onKeyPress={this.onEnter} //allows you to move to the next panel with the enter key
          value={this.codiceReferto}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        >
          <option default value="vuoto"></option>
          {
            this.props.item.map((item, key) => {
              // Use map here
              <option value={item.value} key={key}>{item.text}</option>
            })
          }
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the render method of `CredentialsPanel` class looks like:

```
class CredentialsPanel extends Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    return (
      // ...
      <div className="custom-select">
        <RefertiItems item={this.state.referti} />
      </div>
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it still says "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.item.map is not a function" and " Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.props.item.map is not a function"

Comment: Print this.props.item to know if it's an array

Comment: It's not an array but object. That why you map is not a function. If it's an array, it should display [{}, {}, {}]. More more info, console§.log(`typeof this.props.item`)

Comment: did it, it says it's an object.. what should i do?

Comment: well, response.data is an object, but when i set the state and store response.data into referti[ ], and do console.log(this.state) i get that referti is an array 
 referti: Array(4)
0: {hash_referto: "e9cceea77b", proprietario: "050708", public_key: "0x7343197ba6ee64b5f07322ce1acb0f8f29897689", data_esame: "2019-08-23T00:00:00.000Z", tipo_esame: "urologia", …}
1: {hash_referto: "5bad6", proprietario: "230888", public_key: "0x9628ade5057141a66018b63b78cbdc4a44f055b2", data_esame: "2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z", tipo_esame: "visitia medica generale", …}

Answer (score 0):

maybe `this.state.referti` is not a array data type, so its `map` is not a function, you should `console.log(this.state.referti)` to check its value.

If you use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), you can greatly reduce the type of such error.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try with this**, in this **referti** is the collection on which **.map()** functiona can be invoked. **map()** function contains 2 parameters. 1st : Item from the collection, 2nd : index. Index can be used as key to create unique elements by key.

```
<select>
this.state.referti.map(function(item, index){  
  return <option key={index}>{item}</option>
})
</select>
```